# Not able to change values in rows in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem concerning Pivot Tables. If you create a Pivot Table where you drag some variables to "Rows" and some to "Values", then it is not possible to change any of data concerning the values column. For example, if I try to change the value of "Average of Final Product Value" to something else I am thrown an error:

[image]

However, it is possible to change any of the data in the Row Labels but it is not possible to delete it completely. For an example, I changed "Cheeku" to "a".

[image]

Is there any way to make sure that you can't change the Row Labels in Excel? I made some VBA which does the job, i.e. it looks at a certain range and then by using Worksheet_Change I can undo what was just done. However, I would like to just do it in Excel - if it is possible. My code is

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WatchRange As Range
Dim IntersectRange As Range
Dim nRow As Integer
Dim temp As Variant

With Sheets("Sektor")
    nRow = .Cells(21, 1).End(xlDown).row
End With

Set WatchRange = Range("A21:D" & nRow)
Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)

If IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    'Do Nothing Spectacular
Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

End Sub

To do it in Excel I tried to lock the rows, which did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can edit the name of the column headers in your pivot table.

[image]

I see that you have the yellow bar at the top. I don't speak the language but I assume that it's the usual yellow bar that appears when you can't edit the file and you actually have to press the button to go in "Edit mode".

---

Regarding stopping users from editing the row of the Pivot Table, your idea of locking the rows is correct.

[image]

The only issue is that you need to "Protect" the sheet for the locking to take effect.

[image]